# Dialog displayed black in VS2015

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2015

Recently I upgraded my VS2010 solution to VS2015. After coding a bit and compiling it w/o error I tried to take a look into the `.rc` - the main dialog. The problem here is, that this dialog is displayed completely black without showing controls on it. Clicking around (or using <kbd>TAB</kbd> in the black nothingness, shows that I am able to access the dialog controls. I also have one more dialog without any controls on it. This can be accessed without the 'bug'.

Is this a actual bug or is something else wrong with it ? From my point of view, a control might be causing this, though I didn't find something suspicious in the `.rc` file.
Please leave a comment if you need any more information.

---

**Edit:**

I have now tried to compile it again and it now [`DoModal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5.aspx) returns -1.

> Dialog box could not be created

The dialog does now not show up any more.

---

[image]

Comment: Might be a rendering problem in VS2015, is that a `DLGTEMPLATEEX` based dialog?

Comment: @MarcoA. I've not heard of this yet, is there a way I can check if it is ? Found this [`DLGTEMPLATEEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I don't quite get it.

Comment: Another idea came to mind: can you try moving that "black area" away? It might be an image control that cannot be rendered. Try to delete it (Del key) after selecting it

Comment: @MarcoA. There's no image control in the application. ComboBoxes, Edit Controls, SpinControl, ListControl and Buttons. Even resizing the application does not change anything. I also tried deleting the `.suo` option files. - I have now tried to open it with VS2013 and same result.

Comment: @MarcoA. After compiling it again, the dialog does not show up any more... `DoModal` returns -1. Updated question.

Comment: Edit the .rc file as a text file by hand simplifying the dialog successively until it renders correctly. This will give you a clue what might be wrong. You could also post the relevant part of the .rc file in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed VS2015 on a VM (Windows Server 2008 R2) and the dialog got rendered perfectly.

For some reason it did not render correctly on a Windows 8.1 PC. After changing various changes in the `.rc` file and testing, I created a few dialogs *(also pasted all items from the black dialog into the new <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Copy & Paste),* compared the flags, and changed every single one of them.

Regarding the [`DoModal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5.aspx) returning -1, it seems like the `Style` flag was set wrong after a few changes, my bad I didn't notice. Changing it back from `Child` to `Popup` solved this obvious issue.

As for the rendering not being done correctly (black dialog), it appears to be the property **`Layered`**. After setting this from `True` to `False` it rendered correctly in an instant, changing it back to `True` caused no more issues.

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone if this rare case occurs again.

---

*After comparing both `.rc` files, this has been added by Visual Studio below the version block:*

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
//

IDD_MYBROKEN_DIALOG AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0
END
```